# Trying to Flag Outlook Contacts properly with Python Program

Tags: python, outlook

I wrote a Python program which iterates through a contacts folder and sets a follow-up flag for all contacts which do not currently have one (there are hundreds). Currently the program is set to overwrite current follow-up tags but that will change. The follow ups are added as only the reminder box and the reminder date, the Task Start and Task Due boxes are empty.

This is the code of the program:

```
import win32com.client
import datetime
import pywintypes

#Connect to Outlook
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
namespace = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

#Set up the Contacts folder
contacts_folder = outlook.GetNamespace('MAPI').GetDefaultFolder(10)

#Define yesterday
yesterday = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=-1)
yesterday = datetime.datetime.combine(yesterday, datetime.time(9, 0, 0)) # Set the time to 9:00 AM

print("Begin contact list")

#Iterate over the contacts in the folder
for contact in contacts_folder.Items:
    #Determines that contact is marked as a task
    if contact.IsMarkedAsTask is True:
        #Determines if contact was created on 4/27/23 - This If statement should be REMOVED once the program is edited
        if "4/27/23" in contact.Body:
            contact.MarkAsTask(4) #4 = Contact Due with no Date
            contact.ReminderSet = True
            contact.ReminderTime = yesterday
            contact.TaskSubject = "Follow up"
            contact.Save()

print("Contacts printed successfully!")
```

When I run the code, it does recognize the contacts, puts in the Reminder date, and does not return any errors. However, I do not see the red for most of the contact files without going in and manually editing the flag, even though it is in properly. It even seemingly adds them to the reminder list, but I'm not seeing the red in Outlook. Is it possible to make it show without also adding a Due Date, or is that the only way to get entries to reliably show up? This might be an outlook problem and not a python problem, as there weren't any errors in the code and it seemingly executed properly, but I'm not entirely sure. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Showing items in red is done by the particular view - click "View Settings" on the "View" ribbon, then click "Conditional Formatting". "List" view would have that setting, "Business Card" would not.